# Understanding .htaccess entries

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking at my .htaccess rules and trying to remember what they did when I set them up years back.

Can some one explain what this is meant to do.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://downloads.example.com/.*$  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://downloads.example.com$      [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it checks if HTTP `Referer` doesn't match both of the expression, the request will get redirected to `http://www.example.com/$1`.

E.g.

Referer is:

1. `http://downloads.example.com` - No redirect. Matches rule #1.
2. `http://downloads.example.com/` - No redirect. Matches rule #2.
3. `http://downloads.example.com/foo` - No redirect. Matches rule #2.
4. `http://downloads.example.comm` - Redirect. Matches both rules.

`[NC]` means no case or case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks. If I remember correctly this was added to stop people downloading images and files etc except from the specified domain.